# How can upload photo and saved its aspect ratio in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010

Users of my website  upload their photo with a HTML INPUT (FILE) like this:

```
Fname = File1.PostedFile.FileName.ToString();
int Index = Fname.LastIndexOf("\\");
Fname = Fname.Substring(Index + 1);
string Fname1 = MapPath(Fname);
File1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Fname1);
img =File1.AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory+ Fname;
Image1.ImageUrl = img;
```

Image1 size is 100 * 200 , but I want to save images like 100 * [(h/w)*100].How to to this?

Answer (score 0):

You must resize your image before saving it. Check [this](http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/Resize-Image-in-ASPNET-C.aspx) example

Comment: The link is not true. Please explain more

Comment: First you must get stream from posted file, like this: Stream inputStream = File1.PostedFile.InputStream; Then use method ResizeFromStream from example link, of course you need to change value of newWidth in example